# Erdős and Szemerédi sums and producs

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Erdős and Szemerédi proved that:

$$\max(|A+A|,|A \cdot A|) \gg |A|^{1+\epsilon}$$

It might be that the work of Erdős and Szemerédi does not help me here at all, I did not have to deal with math much in latest years...

> I need to construct the source set A that will give minimum result for max(|A*A|, |A+A|). Lets assume (a > 0, a ∈ A). How would I approach that, are there any existing works in that area or what would be the closest related works?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want. If you really want the minimum of the two then this has little to do with the result you quote. Moreover in which structure do you want to consider the problem?

Comment: To clarify my preceding comment a bit further what confuses me is: "There were also further works that managed to reduce it even further. " I am aware of plenty work that increases the lower bound, yet nothing that reduces anything.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I edited my question, hope it is clearer now

Comment: Have you looked at the paper of Erdos & Szemeredi? Maybe they give a family of subsets that achieve their lower bound. This may also interest you: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Solymosi.pdf

Comment: Yes, I did check Erdos & Szemeredi paper as well as related works, I could not find much that help me, or maybe I simply did not get it... Thanks for Solymosi link, I will check it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson fundamentally *that* is impossible, since the *lower* bound is not sharp. Likely you meant to say something else. Indeed, in their paper they also establish an upper bound  by way of giving an example. See http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1983-18.pdf

Comment: @quid, you are right – I hadn't realized the lower bound wasn't sharp. I should have edited my comment after I saw the Solymosi link.

Comment: Note: this looks suspiciously like a certain [active contest](http://www.azspcs.net/Contest/SumsAndProducts1).

Comment: It would be suspicious if the question would be "how to solve the contest", the question, however, is about the existing publicly available papers on the problem specified earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Erdős and Szemerédi](http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1983-18.pdf) considered the problem of bounding $\max(|A+A|,|A \cdot A|)$. The bounds 
$$ |A|  \ll \max(|A+A|,|A \cdot A|) \ll |A|^2$$ 
are direct and they conjectured that
$$ |A|^{2-\delta}  \ll \max(|A+A|,|A \cdot A|)$$ holds for every positive $\delta$ and showed 
$$ |A|^{1+\epsilon}  \ll \max(|A+A|,|A \cdot A|)$$ for some positive $\epsilon$. 
This lower bound was improved over the years and the current record is (as indicated in Gerry Myerson's comment already) to the best of my knowledge due to Solymosi who showed the lower bound  holds for any  $\epsilon < 1/3$.

Now the question asks for the set that attains the minimum, but this is just not known at all as the above shows, as no-one knows the minimum.

However, the question what the best lower bound one could hope for is was considered in the original paper too, and a construction of sets was given such that $$\max \{|AA|, |A+A|\} < n^2 \exp(-c \log n \log \log n)$$ for some constant $c$. Very roughly, the construction is to consider products of "small" primes, only. The authors say the construction is not optimized. I do not believe there are substantive improvements on it.

Comment: Actually, Solymosi's 4/3 have been slightly improved by Shkredov and Konyagin: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05771.pdf

Comment: Thanks I did not know that.

Comment: Jakub, thanks for the link, should be usefull

Comment: Thanks Quid for the extended description. I believe all "small" numbers should be in the set including primes, it is kind of easy to figure out the first half of the A set as it will be (1, 2, 3, 4 .... k) where k is somewhat k < |A|/2. It is a problem to get the second half of the set. Products of the small primes.. hm.. yea I will go back and check the document again.